# ESP8266 WiFi doesn't reconnect

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I've been reading [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/43376/can-the-wifi-on-esp8266-be-disabled) post while trying to optimize the usage of the WiFi module on my ESP8266.

My main goal was to be able to connect/disconnect (respectively turn on/off) the WiFi module so I can optimize electricity consumption of the chip (I am trying to solar power it).

So, the way I integrated the proposed solution is as follows as I am no where calling deepSleep:

```
#include <RelayModule.h>
#include <ESP8266WIFI.h>
#include <rdm6300.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctime>

extern "C" {
    #include "user_interface.h"  // Required for wifi_station_connect() to work
}
/*...*/
#define RFID_PIN 13
#define RELAY_PIN 10
#define FPM_SLEEP_MAX_TIME 0xFFFFFFF
#define RELAY_OPEN_DURATION 6

RelayModule relay(RELAY_PIN);
Rdm6300 rdm6300;

int relayTurnedOnAt = 0;

void WiFiOn();
void WiFiOff();

void connectToWifi() {
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
     delay(500);
  }
}

void setup() {
  connectToWifi();
  rdm6300.begin(RFID_PIN);
  /*...*/
}

void openFrontDoor() {
  WiFiOn();
  if(relay.isOff()){
    relay.on();
    relayTurnedOnAt = time(0);
  }

  /*Perform some business logic which makes a reference to Services hosted on the Internet*/
}

void lockFrontDoor() {
  relay.off();
  WiFiOff();
}

void loop() {
  // RFID TAG WAS SCANNED
  if (rdm6300.update()){ 
    openFrontDoor();
  }

  if (relay.isOn() && abs(time(0)-relayTurnedOnAt) > RELAY_OPEN_DURATION)
    lockFrontDoor();
}

void WiFiOn() {
    wifi_fpm_do_wakeup();
    wifi_fpm_close();

    //Serial.println("Reconnecting");
    wifi_set_opmode(STATION_MODE);
    wifi_station_connect();
}


void WiFiOff() {
    //Serial.println("diconnecting client and wifi");
    //client.disconnect();
    wifi_station_disconnect();
    wifi_set_opmode(NULL_MODE);
    wifi_set_sleep_type(MODEM_SLEEP_T);
    wifi_fpm_open();
    wifi_fpm_do_sleep(FPM_SLEEP_MAX_TIME);
}
```

The problem here is that once disconnected, I can not get the WiFi module connected back. I need to reset/restart the chip and then I get connected to the internet once again. I would like to be able to fully disable the module when not needed (and save power) and when I need it to submit some stuff to the internet - wake it up, do the job and then bring it back to suspended mode.

Comment: Perhaps the method `wifi_station_disconnect();` drops you WIFI connection at all. Perhaps you have to perform `connectToWifi();` again. But as I don't know the `user_interface.h`,  it is just a guess ;-)..

Comment: why do you use the SDK API. the Arduino WiFi API has all functions to turn off WiFi an turn it back https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/generic-class.html#mode